# Pixi.js - Move object (Text, Graphics) but shader is not following inside (acting like a mask)

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, pixi.js

So i'm trying to render a shader animation inside a Text so i created a Pixi.Text and added Pixi.Filter with my shader code. Everything is fine but when i move the position of my Pixi.Text or PIXI.Graphics i can see that the shader animation is not following so it's like my Text or Graphics is acting like a mask over the shader animation. I feel like it's because of how i apply my texture in my fragmentShader but i can't find any solution.

You can see in the snippet how the texture/shader animation is acting. I would like my shader to stay static inside the text.

Looking forward to having some tips, suggestions, or maybe a direction to follow :)

```js
var fragmentShader = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent


const mauve = 0xDBC4FB
const purple = 0x651B4E


let app = new PIXI.Application({width: 256, height: 256, antialias: true, backgroundAlpha: 0, resolution: 1});
app.view.classList.add("canvas__ulk")
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
app.renderer.autoResize = true;
    app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


/** App */


    document.fonts.load("10px Roboto").then(font => {


        // TEXT
        let message = new PIXI.Text("123", new PIXI.TextStyle({
            fontFamily: "Roboto",
            fontSize: 350,
            fill: "white",
            
        }))
        app.stage.addChild(message)
                
            
        const uniforms = {
            uTime: 0.0,
            uColor: [0.396, 0.105, 0.305],
        }
        let myShader = new PIXI.Filter(null, fragmentShader, uniforms)
        message.filters = [myShader]

        let time = 0

        app.ticker.add(delta => {
    
            time += delta
    
            // update myShader
            uniforms.uTime++
            
            message.y = -window.scrollY
    
        })

    })
```

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, p, ul, body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
header ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

main .logo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 644px;
  text-align: center;
}
main .logo h1 {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 350px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
main .logo h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
main .scroll {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 55px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
main article {
  padding: 55px 65px;
}
main article h2 {
  font-size: 105px;
}
main article p {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 45px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.canvas__ulk {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/6.0.0/browser/pixi.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ULK / TEST PIXI</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>

    </header>


    <main>

        <div class="logo">

            <h1 id="js__ulk-title">123</h1>

        </div>
        <a href="#" class="scroll">SCROLL</a>

        <article>

            <h2>MY TITLE</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi laborum molestias nisi architecto enim corporis debitis dicta, impedit iusto quae nemo vero! Debitis iste possimus atque ducimus! Suscipit pariatur dignissimos exercitationem assumenda qui? Minima facere maiores tempora, fugit nobis error ea, obcaecati quod ex labore dolorem vel, quos quas expedita aut eligendi quo fuga consequuntur.</p>

        </article>


    </main>
    
    <script type="x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
  
precision highp float;

//
// Description : Array and textureless GLSL 2D/3D/4D simplex 
//               noise functions.
//      Author : Ian McEwan, Ashima Arts.
//  Maintainer : ijm
//     Lastmod : 20110813 (stegu)
//     License : Copyright (C) 2011 Ashima Arts. All rights reserved.
//               Distributed under the MIT License. See LICENSE file.
// 

vec3 mod289(vec3 x) {
return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
}

vec4 mod289(vec4 x) {
return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
}

vec4 permute(vec4 x) {
    return mod289(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);
}

vec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r)
{
return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
}

float snoise(vec3 v)
{ 
const vec2  C = vec2(1.0/6.0, 1.0/3.0) ;
const vec4  D = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);

// First corner
vec3 i  = floor(v + dot(v, C.yyy) );
vec3 x0 =   v - i + dot(i, C.xxx) ;

// Other corners
vec3 g = step(x0.yzx, x0.xyz);
vec3 l = 1.0 - g;
vec3 i1 = min( g.xyz, l.zxy );
vec3 i2 = max( g.xyz, l.zxy );

//   x0 = x0 - 0.0 + 0.0 * C.xxx;
//   x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxx;
//   x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxx;
//   x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * C.xxx;
vec3 x1 = x0 - i1 + C.xxx;
vec3 x2 = x0 - i2 + C.yyy; // 2.0*C.x = 1/3 = C.y
vec3 x3 = x0 - D.yyy;      // -1.0+3.0*C.x = -0.5 = -D.y

// Permutations
i = mod289(i); 
vec4 p = permute( permute( permute( 
            i.z + vec4(0.0, i1.z, i2.z, 1.0 ))
        + i.y + vec4(0.0, i1.y, i2.y, 1.0 )) 
        + i.x + vec4(0.0, i1.x, i2.x, 1.0 ));

// Gradients: 7x7 points over a square, mapped onto an octahedron.
// The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 49 (49*6 = 294)
float n_ = 0.142857142857; // 1.0/7.0
vec3  ns = n_ * D.wyz - D.xzx;

vec4 j = p - 49.0 * floor(p * ns.z * ns.z);  //  mod(p,7*7)

vec4 x_ = floor(j * ns.z);
vec4 y_ = floor(j - 7.0 * x_ );    // mod(j,N)

vec4 x = x_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;
vec4 y = y_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;
vec4 h = 1.0 - abs(x) - abs(y);

vec4 b0 = vec4( x.xy, y.xy );
vec4 b1 = vec4( x.zw, y.zw );

//vec4 s0 = vec4(lessThan(b0,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;
//vec4 s1 = vec4(lessThan(b1,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;
vec4 s0 = floor(b0)*2.0 + 1.0;
vec4 s1 = floor(b1)*2.0 + 1.0;
vec4 sh = -step(h, vec4(0.0));

vec4 a0 = b0.xzyw + s0.xzyw*sh.xxyy ;
vec4 a1 = b1.xzyw + s1.xzyw*sh.zzww ;

vec3 p0 = vec3(a0.xy,h.x);
vec3 p1 = vec3(a0.zw,h.y);
vec3 p2 = vec3(a1.xy,h.z);
vec3 p3 = vec3(a1.zw,h.w);

//Normalise gradients
vec4 norm = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(p0,p0), dot(p1,p1), dot(p2, p2), dot(p3,p3)));
p0 *= norm.x;
p1 *= norm.y;
p2 *= norm.z;
p3 *= norm.w;

// Mix final noise value
vec4 m = max(0.6 - vec4(dot(x0,x0), dot(x1,x1), dot(x2,x2), dot(x3,x3)), 0.0);
m = m * m;
return 42.0 * dot( m*m, vec4( dot(p0,x0), dot(p1,x1), 
                                dot(p2,x2), dot(p3,x3) ) );
} 

#pragma glslify: export(snoise)


precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;
uniform float uTime;
uniform vec3 uColor;


float rf = 405.4;
float gf = 1022.0;
float bf = 720.2;

vec3 red = vec3(0.901, 0.074, 0.235);
vec3 mauve = vec3(0.854, 0.772, 1);
vec3 orange = vec3(0.929, 0.443, 0.231);


float clampBetween(float x, float pmin, float pmax, float cmin, float cmax){
    return ((x - pmin) / (pmax - pmin)) * (cmax - cmin) + cmin;
}


vec4 getPlasma1(float noiseValue, float colorNoise){

    vec4 noisePerturbationColor = vec4(noiseValue, noiseValue, noiseValue, 1.);


    vec3 targetColor = mix(
        mauve,
        red,
        colorNoise
    );

    
    float clampedValue = clamp(noiseValue, 0., 1.);

    // black go uColor & others go targetColor
    noisePerturbationColor.rgb = mix(
        uColor,
        mauve,
        clampedValue
    ); 


    float threshold = .7;

    if(noiseValue >= threshold){

        noisePerturbationColor.rgb = mix(
            noisePerturbationColor.rgb,
            orange,
            clampBetween(clampedValue, threshold, 1., .0, 1.)
        ); 

    }


    threshold = .86;

    if(noiseValue >= threshold){

        noisePerturbationColor.rgb = mix(
            noisePerturbationColor.rgb,
            red,
            clampBetween(clampedValue, threshold, 1., .0, 1.)
        ); 

    }

    return noisePerturbationColor;

}

vec4 getPlasma2(float noiseValue, float noise2Value){

    vec4 noisePerturbationColor = vec4(noiseValue, noiseValue, noiseValue, 1.);

    /** APPLY MAUVE **/

    float threshold = 0.;
    float maxLissage = .05;

    // lissage
    noisePerturbationColor.rgb = mix(
        uColor,
        mauve,
        clamp(clampBetween(
            noiseValue,
            threshold, maxLissage,
            .0, 1.
        ), 0., 1.)
    );


    /** APPLY ORANGE **/
    threshold = .34;
    maxLissage = .84;

    // lissage
    noisePerturbationColor.rgb = mix(
        noisePerturbationColor.rgb,
        orange,
        clamp(clampBetween(
            noiseValue,
            threshold, maxLissage,
            .0, 1.
        ), 0., 1.)
    );

    /** APPLY RED **/
    threshold = .87;
    maxLissage = 1.;

    // lissage
    noisePerturbationColor.rgb = mix(
        noisePerturbationColor.rgb,
        red,
        clamp(clampBetween(
            noiseValue,
            threshold, maxLissage,
            .0, 1.
        ), 0., 1.)
    );


    return noisePerturbationColor;
}

void main()
{


    // noise
        float t = uTime * .005;
        vec2 uv = 1.0*vTextureCoord;

        float noisePrecision = 2.4;

        float value = snoise(vec3(uv.x * noisePrecision, uv.y * noisePrecision, t/2.0));

        float colorNoise = snoise(vec3(uv.x * noisePrecision, uv.y * noisePrecision, -3. + t/2.0));
        float orangeNoise = snoise(vec3(uv.x * 2., uv.y * 2., t/2.0));

        float r = (sin(radians(value*rf+100.0*t)) +1.0)/2.0;
        float g = (sin(radians(value*gf+100.0*t)) +1.0)/2.0;
        float b = (sin(radians(value*bf+100.0*t)) +1.0)/2.0;
        

        // vec4 noisePerturbationColor = vec4(pow(r,10.0)+r,0,1.0-b,1);
        // vec4 noisePerturbationColor = vec4(r,r+g/b,r,1);
        // vec4 noisePerturbationColor = vec4(value, value, value, 1.);
        // vec4 noisePerturbationColor = getPlasma1(value, colorNoise);
        vec4 noisePerturbationColor = getPlasma2(value, orangeNoise);

    // noise

    // get from uSampler
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);

    
    gl_FragColor = noisePerturbationColor * textureColor;
}
    
    </script>

    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```